# netlogo in java

Tags: java, netbeans, netlogo

I need to create a large library to determine turtles' behaviour  and need an interface to show the results after they completed their behaviours. Is it possible to run Netlogo in Netbeans ? If possible , does it create problems after a while such as limited reaching to codes ,slows down  or anything else?

Comment: see my answer at http://groups.yahoo.com/group/netlogo-users/message/13983

Comment: I think you could export your results as a csv file after the model has finished its run, so you could analyze the results using other tools.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can use the "HeadlessWorkspace" functionality to run NetLogo programs from within a Java program (or unit test). So, using this, you can definitely step through responses from a model within a NetBeans debugging session (e.g. querying reporters).

Please see the following page for the projects' description of this functionality:

https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Controlling-API

Answer (score -1):

NetLogo is a Java program which implements both an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) for the NetLogo programming language, as well as a NetLogo interpreter. NetBeans is an IDE for  Java (and other languages, but not NetLogo).

So, no, you cannot run NetLogo programs in Netbeans. Netlogo programs only run in the Netlogo IDE.

You are also asking about speed. Yes, a NetLogo program probably runs slower than an equivalent program written in Java. It depends on the specific program.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But when I imported the Netlogo.jar to Netbeans ,It can see  the "import org.nlogo.* " library .So is this library related to Netlogo or another something?

Comment: That is the netlogo program. You can run it, but you can't edit. They do not make the source code available.

Comment: However, they do allow you to write Java code that extends Netlogo (adds a new command). See https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API

Comment: Jose, we do make the source code available; NetLogo 5.0 is open source. The source code is at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo